# Duplicacy and Scaling issue with mqtt from spring boot service as a subscriber

Tags: java, spring-boot, mqtt, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

We have one service in java/spring boot. In this service, we subscribe to the MQTT topic and we get data from the topic.
The issue is we have multiple pods for each service. So when MQTT broadcasts the data, then all the pods are getting data and do same action. how can restrict to only pod.
The second issue is scaling issue. We are expecting around 200 message coming to mqtt per second. And while doing load testing we saw that some of the messages are delayed or lost.

We are using aws iot core. And for a temporary solution, we have used iot rule and action as 'http post'. So whenever any message is received by mqtt, it triggers http call to the service. And as the pods are load balanced, hence call goes to only one service. This solves the duplicacy issue but we are still skeptical about scale.

I know that with mqtt5, they have introduced shared subscription but due to some restriction on firmware upgrade, we cannot upgrade from mqtt3 to mqtt5.
Is there any other solution or best practice we can follow.

Comment: It looks like AWS IoT Core [now supports shared subscriptions](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/04/aws-iot-core-mqtt5-shared-subscriptions-cloudwatch-metrics/) (for both v3 and v5); there is a [how to article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/how-to-get-started-with-the-new-shared-subscriptions-in-aws-iot-core/). You don't mention whether you can control which topics the messages are published on so this may, or may not, help.

Comment: @Brits Thanks for the reference. I have tried implementing shared subscription but facing issue. Added question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76582116/java-spring-boot-subscriber-implementation-getting-no-message-when-using-mqtt-sh). Please take a look on it.